# how to align different table row elements in html table

Tags: html, css

I created a html table with 2 rows.
2nd row has to be a colspan="4"
please help me to align this elements.
action text and two buttons are centered to given width.
and Licence Key : ZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZ align right,
But it has not align responsiveness.
I want to align Licence Key : ZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZ as I below the image

```html
<table width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr className="custom-tr">
      <th className="custom-th" width="35%">
        Product Name
      </th>
      <th className="custom-th" width="20%">
        Subscription Plan
      </th>
      <th className="custom-th" width="15%">
        Purchased Date
      </th>
      <th className="custom-th" width="30%" style="text-align: center;">
        Actions
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr className="custom-tr">
      <td className="custom-td">
        ESSENTIAL PC ANTIVIRUS
      </td>
      <td className="custom-td">
        MONTHLY PLAN
      </td>
      <td className="custom-td">
        4/9/2020
      </td>
      <td className="custom-td" style="text-align: center;">
        <button className="border-btn blue-border cursor">
              View License Key
            </button>
        <button className="border-btn danger-border cursor">
              Unsubscribe
            </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr className="custom-tr">
      <td colspan="4" className="custom-td p-r-21" style="text-align: right;">
        <span className="icon-color">
              Licence Key :
            </span> ZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZ
        <i className="f18 icon-color m-r-5 cursor fas fa-envelope m-l-20" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: This is what I got so far]

[image: Need to align like this]

Comment: Sorry, can't see image and could you post your html code, with css?

Comment: It would help us help if you can give code reference.  Can you put up the code on stackbliz so that we better understand your problem.

Comment: I added images and codes

Comment: sorry for the mistake

Comment: I don't think you need an extra `<tr>`. Add the licence below the buttons. You will have better control over the layout.

Comment: @NickHTTPS yes,Good idea. But that was the design, I can not change that. I have to do that, can you please tell me how to do that alignments.

Comment: @WathsalaDeSilva , so you cant change the HTML?

Comment: @YaswanthJg I can change the HTML, But I cant change the design. It need to be as I mentioned above image

Comment: @WathsalaDeSilva , please check my answer. add one more td, but with colspan as '3'

Answer (score 0):

I would add the **Licence key** directly in the td:

```
<table width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr className="custom-tr">
      <th className="custom-th" width="35%">
        Product Name
      </th>
      <th className="custom-th" width="20%">
        Subscription Plan
      </th>
      <th className="custom-th" width="15%">
        Purchased Date
      </th>
      <th className="custom-th" width="30%" style="text-align: center;">
        Actions
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr className="custom-tr">
      <td className="custom-td">
        ESSENTIAL PC ANTIVIRUS
      </td>
      <td className="custom-td">
        MONTHLY PLAN
      </td>
      <td className="custom-td">
        4/9/2020
      </td>
      <td className="custom-td" style="text-align: center;">
        <button className="border-btn blue-border cursor">
          View License Key
        </button>
        <button className="border-btn danger-border cursor">
          Unsubscribe
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr className="custom-tr">
      <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
      <td
        className="custom-td p-r-21"
        style="text-align: center;"
      >
        <span className="icon-color">
          Licence Key :
        </span>
        ZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZ
        <i
          className="f18 icon-color m-r-5 cursor fas fa-envelope m-l-20"
          aria-hidden="true"
        ></i>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

It's not very semantic to add multiple empty `<td>` but this should do the trick based on your design.

Comment: I need that extra tr. that was the design. As I mentioned above, that was the design

Comment: If you just want the extra `<tr>` to show the line division between the buttons and the licence key you can just go for the `<hr>` instead of the `<tr>`.

Answer (score 0):

**Just add one more TD in the second row... **
Please check the below snippet

```css
body {
margin:0;
}

table {
border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td, table th {
border: 1px solid #ddd;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr className="custom-tr">
      <th className="custom-th" width="35%">
        Product Name
      </th>
      <th className="custom-th" width="20%">
        Subscription Plan
      </th>
      <th className="custom-th" width="15%">
        Purchased Date
      </th>
      <th className="custom-th" width="30%" style="text-align: center;">
        Actions
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <!-- first row -->
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><button>first but</button>
        <button>second</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!-- second row -->
      <td colspan="3"></td>
      <td style="text-align:left; ">
        <!-- license info -->
        zz----zz-z-z-zzz--z-
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I did this, If I do that, "action" - table header not align properly, Not responsive in large device.I need that  perfectly align in the design(2nd image) I mentioned above

Comment: you can add the "text-align: left" for td's containing button and license... And, actions header can have 'text-align: center' .. also, all other cells can have text-align:left..